# Using django-admin on django-nonrel, using App Engine models

Tags: django-admin, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

I am creating an Django app for Google App Engine. I am using django-nonrel but am using Google App Engine models.

I am wanting to also use Django's admin site.

My **models.py** for airlines app is:

> ```
> from google.appengine.ext import db
>
> class Airline(db.Model):
>  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
>  description = db.TextProperty()
>  notes = db.TextProperty()
>
>  class Meta:
>   verbose_name_plural = 'Airlines'
>
>  def __unicode__(self):
>   return self.name
> ```

My **admin.py** is:

> ```
> from django.contrib import admin
> from airlines.models import *
>
> admin.site.register(Airline)
> ```

I do GAE runserver and get the following error:

> ```
> TypeError at /admin/
>
> 'PropertiedClass' object is not iterable
> ```

Can I not use Google App Engine models with **django-nonrel** admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use App Engine models with django-nonrel. You have to use django models. This way your code gets reusable and allows you to switch off of App Engine and to use your code with another database.